# Graphviz Decision tree display separately for the same elements

Tags: python-3.x, graphviz

I have the codes here,

```
import graphviz as gv
d=gv.Digraph()
d.edge('a','b')
d.edge('a','c')
d.edge('b','c')
```

the output is as pic:

[image]

How can I get a graph like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not using Python, I only have a pure `graphviz` answer but you should be able to translate that easily into Python.

You need to do two things:

- Create four nodes, not three, and give them the label you want
- Put the nodes you want to have on the same level into a `rank = same` instruction (not strictly necessary in the example context but may be needed for more complex graphs)

Here we go:

```
digraph so 
{
    n_1[ label = "a" ];
    n_2[ label = "b" ];
    n_3[ label = "c" ];
    n_4[ label = "c" ];

    { rank = same; n_2 n_3 }

    n_1 -> { n_2 n_3 };
    n_2 -> n_4;
}
```

which gives you

[image]

Comment: When necessary you can easily test something at http://www.webgraphviz.com/